# Chaining ActiveRecord scopes leads to undefined method for []:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, rspec2, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I got this error only in test environment with RSpec. The code works in all other environments including Rails console.

Given this code

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :flag, -> {where(flag: nil) } 
end
```

When I call `User.where(expired_at: nil).flag`

Then it results in `undefined method`flag`for []:Array`

I'm using Rails 4.1.1 and rspec-rails 2.14.0.

Comment: Do you have `User.where` method overwrote?

Comment: No, I have not overwritten the User.where method.

Comment: Of course, `User` class inherits after `ActiveRecord::Base`?

Comment: Ok, this is quite weird. What does `User.method(:where).source_location` return?

Comment: /.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-mocks-2.14.6/lib/rspec/mocks/method_double.rb

That helped me a lot to find the answer: in my RSpec example I do User.stub(:where).and_return([]).

Answer (score 0):

With that stub, your "User.where(expired_at: nil)" will return [], which your code will take and then try to call "flag" on it. Since arrays in Ruby do not have a method called "flag", the exception you're seeing gets thrown. There are a few ways you can handle this.

1) Don't stub that call. Just let the framework handle it (and yes it will attempt to hit the db which may be what you're trying to avoid here but still, it's an option).

2) Return a test double and not an empty array, as in

```
results = double(:expired_users, flag: [])
User.stub(:where).and_return(expired_users)
```

See how flag is stubbed out there on ":expired_users" to return an empty array?

3) Add a method to your user model which basically runs what you want and stub that out, for example:

```
class User
  def self.flagged_expired_users
    where(expired_at: nil).flag
  end
end
```

and in the spec

```
User.stub(:flagged_expired_users).and_return([])
```

I prefer #3 myself since that style of testing/mocking tends to be less brittle in my experience, but ymmv.

Answer (score -1):

In my RSpec example I call `User.stub(:where).and_return([])`.

I replaced it by `User.stub(:where).and_return(User.all)`

Comment: If you're just going to have the stub return User.all, which hits the database, just remove this stub completely. If you want it to return some data, create user records that meet the criteria (that are expired and flagged).